# Как реализовано разыменовывание указателя в C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, указатели, операторы

Почему код `int* p = &(*(&n))` корректно работает?
Я, представляя себя компилятором, воспроизвожу код так:

- `&n`: возвращаем адрес переменной n
- `*(&n)`: возвращаем число, лежащее по этому адресу
- `&(*(&n))`: возвращаем адрес, по которому хранится число, которое мы временно только что вычислили (?)

Как компилятор узнает, какой адрес у выражения `*(&n)`?

Comment: а никак: `mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:n` https://godbolt.org/g/DGEAzB

Comment: @pavel  можно поподробнее? Я не знаю ассемблер

Comment: по простому - *& уничтожают друг друга

Comment: @pavel А как именно "уничтожают"? Я пишу простенький интерпретатор своего языка с подобием указателей, и не могу понять, как реализовать это взаимоуничтожение * и &

Comment: Адрес переводится в указатель, указатель переводится в адрес. Одна операция добавляет смещение, что бы указывать на значение, вторая наоборот убавляет смещение, что бы получить адрес указателя. Это если по простому совсем.

Comment: @AlexKrass смещение означается, что в какой-то ячейке памяти хранится адрес переменной, а в соседней ячейке хранится значение переменной по этому адресу; и операции * и & только перемещаются между этими ячейками?

Comment: @AnatoliySultanov, грубо говоря да. Ну конечно компилятор еще проверяет типы, учитывает их и если надо преобразовывает в зависимости от нужной логики.

Comment: @pavel: Такое безусловное "уничтожение" определено только в С. В С++ результат `*` может быть не определен, и ситуация на спасается "уничтожающим" `&`.

Comment: @AnT а когда это будет UB? Именно в такой записи, н наоборот. Пример можно?

Comment: @pavel: Именно в такой, я думаю, никогда не будет, если аргумент внутреннего `&` подразумевается корректным.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ошибка кроется в выделенном слове данного предложения

> &(*(&n)): возвращаем адрес, по которому хранится число, которое мы
>   **временно** только что вычислили (?)

Дело в том, что согласно, например, стандарту C++ (5.3.1 Unary operators)

> The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it
>   is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a
>   function type and the result is an **lvalue referring to the object or
>   function to which the expression points.**

никакого временного объекта не создается.

То же самое записано в C стандарте (6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators)

> 4 The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a
>   function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an
>   object, **the result is an lvalue designating the object.**

Также в этом же разделе стандарта C записано

> 3 The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the
>   operand has type ‘‘type’’, the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’.
>   **If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both
>   were omitted**, except that the constraints on the operators still
>   apply and the result is not an lvalue.

Так что выражение

```
&(*(&n))
```

эквивалентно исходному выражению

```
&n
```

с учетом упомянутых ограничений.

**Примечание.** 
Упомянутые в цитате ограничения порой существенны. Например, результат этой C-программы где используется связка операторов `&*`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[10];

    printf( "sizeof( a ) = %zu\n", sizeof( a ) );
    printf( "sizeof( &*a ) = %zu\n", sizeof( &*a ) );

    return 0;
}
```

будет следующим

```
sizeof( a ) = 40
sizeof( &*a ) = 4
```

То есть операнд первого оператора  `sizeof` является `lvalue`, в то время как операнд второго оператора `sizeof` будет уже `rvalue` в связи с применением связки `&*`.
**[Конец примечания]**

В связи с этим есть забавный побочный эффект. Так как функции в выражениях преобразуются к указателю на функцию, то можно вызов функции записать, например, в следующем виде

```
#include <iostream>

void f() { std::cout << "Hello, pointers!" << std::endl; }

int main() 
{
    ( **********f )();
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    return 0;
}
```

Этот прием полезен, когда вашу продуктивность оценивают по числу набранных символов в программе.:)

Comment: Я вот читаю... Про функции понятно, а вот про выражение в топике - не очень. Сейчас нет компилятора, проверить не могу, но что произойдет? Можете описать процесс?

Comment: @Alexander Про какое выражение вы говорите, про вызов функции?,

Comment: Нет, про `&(*(&n))`.

Comment: @Alexander &n - дает адрес переменной n. Можно представить как int *tmp = &n; Применяя разыменование к указателю *p, мы снова получим n, то есть, как написано в стандарте, lvalue, которая ссылается на n.

Comment: А, понятно. Они действительно взаимоуничтожаются.  Правда, при этом происходят ненужные вычисления (может быть какие-то компиляторы это и оптимизируют).

Comment: @Alexander Смотрите мой дополненный ответ.